# Defining Collections without specific type

Tags: java, collections

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Set vals = new TreeSet();
       vals.add("one");
       vals.add(1);
       vals.add("two");
       System.out.println(vals);
}
```

(i)-What does it mean to define a collection without giving it a type?For what purpose
does it made for?

(ii)-Can I add different type to the collection any way?

Here's an example- There's no compilation error, though it's warning me.

But, as excepted, there's a run time error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Defining a collection (or any typed class) without specifying a type argument is called using a raw type. It exists **only** for backwards compatibility and should not be used in new code. If effectively removes all effects of generics on the type.
2. Generally, you could define your set to accept `Object`: it would then accept all values: `Set<Object> vals = new HashSet<Object>()`. *However* this won't work for `TreeSet`, because it needs its values to be [`Comparable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) with each other. *If* you want to add arbitrary types to the same `TreeSet` (which is usually a sign of some architecture problems, i.e. a design smell), then you'll need to implement your own [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that can compare arbitrary elements and pass that into [the appropriate `TreeSet` constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Comparator%29).

Comment: `Set<Object> vals = new TreeSet<Object>()` will blow up with a `ClassCastException` if you first add an `Integer` and then try to add a `String` to it.

Comment: @Sahil Muthoo: oops, I didn't actually think of `TreeSet` specifically, you're right. I've clarified that now.

Comment: Set a_set_that_can_be_initialized_to_whatever_generic_type is NOT the same as Set<Object> a_set_that_can_only_be_initialized_to_generic_type_Object

Comment: @Andrei: I don't understand. Are you talking about the difference of `Set<?>` and `Set<Object>`? If so, then I don't think that's relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

i) It means it can have any object. If you want to add any type. (Generally a design problem)

ii) Using type erasure you can.

> But, as excepted, there's a run time error.

Getting an error at compile time is usually better than getting a runtime error. (Easier to find and fix)

Answer (score 1):

Upto Java 1.4 there were no Generics. All collections could only contain `Object` and you would have to classcast the object when using the object after taking it out of the collection. So you would do

```
Set vals = new Treeset();
String s = (String)vals.get(0);
```

instead of

```
Set<String> vals = new Treeset<String>();
String s = vals.get(0);
```

Putting different types of objects that have no shared interface or superclass is very bad practice since you wont know how to handle the object when you take it out of the collection.

Answer (score 1):

```
private Set<JPanel> s1;

public void run() {
    aMethod(s1);
}

/* line 7 */ public void aMethod(Set panels) {

}
```

If you refactor the above code by changing the 7th line to

```
public void aMethod(Set<Object> panels) {
```

it will no longer compile. If you refactor that line to

```
public void aMethod(Set<?> panels) {
```

it will still compile as before, and as an extra bonus you will no longer have the "Set is raw..." warning

Comment: Good point! You should never underestimate the importance of refactoring readiness of your code.